# How to know the order of update with Domain context SubmitChanges?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, entity-framework-5

Suppose I have 3 entities generated from EF, say tab1, tab2 and tab3. In SL app, I call SubmitChanges to save data to DB, all changes will be process by WCF and EF automatically.

Question is: how can I know the order of Update operation in Database?

I need to know this because I have triggers on those tables and need to know the order of the updating.

Comment: If the triggers are modifying the same entities as EF, chances are they will not play nice together.  You should consider dropping the triggers and re-implementing that code in .NET.  We override the SaveChanges method on our context and run trigger-like logic there.

Comment: Thank you. Trigger from legacy system and I don't want to implement it in .NET code because that would cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Order of operations is internal EF behavior = you cannot reliably know what order of operations will be used.

Comment: @KentZhou As Ladislav said, you really cannot know what order is used.  Your best bet would be to call SubmitChanges after each insert.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I needed to control the execution order of the updates, but wasn't able to find any answer. The workaround was to have separate submitchanges to update tables in the order that I need.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to override the PeristChangeSet() in your DomainService and manually control the order of saves. Just do nothing in your regular update/insert statements. Here's some pseudocode for a saving a document exmmple to explain my answer:

```
[Insert]
public void InsertDocument(MyDocument objDocument) { }

[Update]
public void UpdateDocument(MyDocument objDocument) { }


protected override bool PersistChangeSet()
{
    try {
        // have to save document first to get its id....
        MyDocument objDocumentBeingSaved = null;
        foreach (ChangeSetEntry CSE in ChangeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(i => i.Entity is MyDocument)) {
            var changedEntity = (MyDocument)CSE.Entity;
            objDocumentBeingSaved = documentRepository.SaveDocument(changedEntity);
            break; // only one doc
        }

        if (objDocumentBeingSaved == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("CreateDocumentDomainService.PersistChangeSet(): Error saving document information. Document is null in entity set.");

        // save document assignments after saving document object
        foreach (ChangeSetEntry CSE in ChangeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(i => i.Entity is DocumentAssignment)) {
            var changedEntity = (DocumentAssignment)CSE.Entity;
            changedEntity.DocumentId = objDocumentBeingSaved.Id;
            changedEntity.Id = documentRepository.SaveDocumentAssignment(objDocumentBeingSaved, changedEntity);
        }

        // save line items after saving document assignments
        foreach (ChangeSetEntry CSE in ChangeSet.ChangeSetEntries.Where(i => i.Entity is LineItem)) {
            var changedEntity = (LineItem)CSE.Entity;
            changedEntity.DocumentId = objDocumentBeingSaved.Id;
            changedEntity.Id = documentRepository.SaveLineItem(objDocumentBeingSaved, changedEntity);
        }
        documentRepository.GenerateDocumentNumber(objDocumentBeingSaved.Id);
    }
    catch {
        // ....
        throw;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This kind of hardcode solution is very hard for my situation. There are so many tables in DB(then in ChangeSet each time to submitchanges). When EF SaveChanges, it should use a kind of order for those entities in changeset. Is it possible to change the order before  submit it to database?